# How to print(by printer) Excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, printing, apache-poi

I would like to print by connected printer a spreadsheet created with Apache POI. How to do it? I asked similar question a year ago and I have to say: I do not mean openning `.xls` file and using `ctrl+p` ; ).

The sheet is:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PrintSetup;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class BusinessPlan {

    private static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM", Locale.US);

    private static final String[] titles = { "ID", "Project Name", "Owner", "Days", "Start", "End" };

    //sample data to fill the sheet.
    private static final String[][] data = { { "1.0", "Marketing Research Tactical Plan", "J. Dow", "70", "9-Jul", null, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" }, null, { "1.1", "Scope Definition Phase", "J. Dow", "10", "9-Jul", null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.1.1", "Define research objectives", "J. Dow", "3", "9-Jul", null, "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.1.2", "Define research requirements", "S. Jones", "7", "10-Jul", null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.1.3", "Determine in-house resource or hire vendor", "J. Dow", "2", "15-Jul", null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, null, { "1.2", "Vendor Selection Phase", "J. Dow", "19", "19-Jul", null, null, "x", "x", "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null },
            { "1.2.1", "Define vendor selection criteria", "J. Dow", "3", "19-Jul", null, null, "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.2.2", "Develop vendor selection questionnaire", "S. Jones, T. Wates", "2", "22-Jul", null, null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.2.3", "Develop Statement of Work", "S. Jones", "4", "26-Jul", null, null, null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.2.4", "Evaluate proposal", "J. Dow, S. Jones", "4", "2-Aug", null, null, null, null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.2.5", "Select vendor", "J. Dow", "1", "6-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, "x", null, null, null, null, null, null }, null, { "1.3", "Research Phase", "G. Lee", "47", "9-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x" },
            { "1.3.1", "Develop market research information needs questionnaire", "G. Lee", "2", "9-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, "x", null, null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.3.2", "Interview marketing group for market research needs", "G. Lee", "2", "11-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, "x", "x", null, null, null, null, null }, { "1.3.3", "Document information needs", "G. Lee, S. Jones", "1", "13-Aug", null, null, null, null, null, null, "x", null, null, null, null, null }, };

    /**
     * create a library of cell styles
     */
    private static Map<String, CellStyle> createStyles(Workbook wb) {
        Map<String, CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<String, CellStyle>();
        DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();

        CellStyle style;
        Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
        headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setFont(headerFont);
        styles.put("header", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setFont(headerFont);
        style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
        styles.put("header_date", style);

        Font font1 = wb.createFont();
        font1.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        style.setFont(font1);
        styles.put("cell_b", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setFont(font1);
        styles.put("cell_b_centered", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFont(font1);
        style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
        styles.put("cell_b_date", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFont(font1);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
        styles.put("cell_g", style);

        Font font2 = wb.createFont();
        font2.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
        font2.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        style.setFont(font2);
        styles.put("cell_bb", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setFont(font1);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
        styles.put("cell_bg", style);

        Font font3 = wb.createFont();
        font3.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
        font3.setColor(IndexedColors.DARK_BLUE.getIndex());
        font3.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        style.setFont(font3);
        style.setWrapText(true);
        styles.put("cell_h", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        style.setWrapText(true);
        styles.put("cell_normal", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setWrapText(true);
        styles.put("cell_normal_centered", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        style.setWrapText(true);
        style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("d-mmm"));
        styles.put("cell_normal_date", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        style.setIndention((short) 1);
        style.setWrapText(true);
        styles.put("cell_indented", style);

        style = createBorderedStyle(wb);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        styles.put("cell_blue", style);

        return styles;
    }

    private static CellStyle createBorderedStyle(Workbook wb) {
        CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        return style;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb;

        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-xls"))
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        else
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

        Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(wb);//style sa wkladane do mapy

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Business Plan");

        //turn off gridlines
        sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
        sheet.setPrintGridlines(false);
        sheet.setFitToPage(true);
        sheet.setHorizontallyCenter(true);
        PrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
        printSetup.setLandscape(true);

        //the following three statements are required only for HSSF
        sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
        printSetup.setFitHeight((short) 1);
        printSetup.setFitWidth((short) 1);

        //the header row: centered text in 48pt font
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        headerRow.setHeightInPoints(12.75f);
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(titles[i]);
            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
        }
        //columns for 11 weeks starting from 9-Jul
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        calendar.setTime(fmt.parse("9-Jul"));
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(titles.length + i);
            cell.setCellValue(calendar);
            cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header_date"));
            calendar.roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, true);
        }
        //freeze the first row
        sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);

        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        int rownum = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++, rownum++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
            if (data[i] == null)
                continue;

            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                String styleName;
                boolean isHeader = i == 0 || data[i - 1] == null;
                switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    if (isHeader) {
                        styleName = "cell_b";
                        cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(data[i][j]));
                    } else {
                        styleName = "cell_normal";
                        cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (isHeader) {
                        styleName = i == 0 ? "cell_h" : "cell_bb";
                    } else {
                        styleName = "cell_indented";
                    }
                    cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    styleName = isHeader ? "cell_b" : "cell_normal";
                    cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    styleName = isHeader ? "cell_b_centered" : "cell_normal_centered";
                    cell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(data[i][j]));
                    break;
                case 4: {
                    calendar.setTime(fmt.parse(data[i][j]));
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    cell.setCellValue(calendar);
                    styleName = isHeader ? "cell_b_date" : "cell_normal_date";
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    int r = rownum + 1;
                    String fmla = "IF(AND(D" + r + ",E" + r + "),E" + r + "+D" + r + ",\"\")";
                    cell.setCellFormula(fmla);
                    styleName = isHeader ? "cell_bg" : "cell_g";
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    styleName = data[i][j] != null ? "cell_blue" : "cell_normal";
                }

                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get(styleName));
            }
        }

        //group rows for each phase, row numbers are 0-based
        sheet.groupRow(4, 6);
        sheet.groupRow(9, 13);
        sheet.groupRow(16, 18);

        //set column widths, the width is measured in units of 1/256th of a character width
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 256 * 6);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 256 * 33);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 256 * 20);
        sheet.setZoom(3, 4);

        // Write the output to a file
        String file = "businessplan.xls";
        if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook)
            file += "x";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ressurect this post, but did you find a way to do it?